# airflow: why it still shows dags after I logged out?

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow, I have managed it up and running and I can access the web GUI and see the example DAGs, however, after I clicked on the top right corner logout icon and logged out, the DAGs are still available on the front end instead of presumably no web GUI at all?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's is because by default web authentication is turned off.

Enable web authentication by adding the following to your `airflow.cfg` file:

```py
[webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
```

and make sure that they is no other duplicate value for `auth_backend` in `airflow.cfg` file.

Then create a user for the Web UI:

```py
# navigate to the airflow installation directory
$ cd ~/airflow
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:28:08)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import airflow
>>> from airflow import models, settings
>>> from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
>>> user = PasswordUser(models.User())
>>> user.username = 'new_user_name'
>>> user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
>>> user.password = 'set_the_password'
>>> session = settings.Session()
>>> session.add(user)
>>> session.commit()
>>> session.close()
>>> exit()
```

Now when you try to access the web ui, it will ask for user and password. And when you log out you won't be able to see the DAGs.

To integrate it with LDAP: https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#ldap

Comment: Thank you very much, adding single user manually is great but I like more to integrate it with LDAP or PAM authentication, is it possible? how?

Comment: Yes that can be done as well, check https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#ldap